# How to include css files to gulp-sass?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

Basically I have this gulp task snippet:

```
var sassStream = gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe(plugins.sass({
            includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation-apps/scss']
        }));
```

I want to include in the end result (being `app.css`) `bower_components/A.css` and `bower_components/B.css`.
Note that they aren't `.scss` files and that I can't modify them since being part of vendors.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`event-stream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) and [`gulp-concat`](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat):

```
var es     = require('event-stream');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

...
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  var sassStream = gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss').pipe(plugins.sass(...));
  var cssStream  = gulp.src('bower_components/{A,B}.css');

  return es.merge(sassStream, cssStream)
           .pipe(concat('app.css'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```